# Usage of comma and parallel verbs in this sentence

Tags: commas, clauses, parallelism, is-it-a-rule

> Interestingly enough, a large number of the Facebook-based business ventures [have been formed][,] 
>   and [are run] and [managed] by women, 
>   which directly and indirectly contributes to women's empowerment in the country.

My first question is about the Comma in the third bracket before *and*. The rule of the Comma before *and* is:

- The Comma before *and* joining two independent clauses
- The Comma before *and* in lists of three or more items and etc.

Source: [Using a Comma before “And”](https://getitwriteonline.com/articles/when-to-use-comma-before-and/)

But `a large number of the Facebook-based business ventures have been formed` and `[are run] and [managed] by women` are not independent clauses. So why the comma is used there?

The second question is about maintaining the parallel verbs which are `[have been formed]` and `[are run] and [managed]` which share the same subject. Shouldn't the verbs sharing the same subject be the same tense?

Source: [Using Parallel Verbs](https://www.ecenglish.com/learnenglish/lessons/using-parallel-verbs)

Comment: Looks like a list to me. Ventures have been 1. Formed, 2. Run, and 3. Managed by women. Second question I am not able to explain, but I can tell you that it won't make sense if the tense is the same. Before the comma is past tense, after the comma is present.

Comment: The comma 'rules' are not absolute and are 'given' / used to (1) guarantee clarity of meaning, (2) aid reading, (3) show emphasis by signalling say dramatic pauses, (4 ) fit in with a certain style. If too many commas of different types are evident in a sentence, it is best to rephrase. Especially when different rules seem to be in play and it is difficult to work out which should take precedence. // 'Interestingly enough, a large number of the Facebook-based business ventures were formed, and are run and managed, by women. This directly and indirectly contributes to women's empowerment....'

Answer (score 1):

The first highlighted comma incorrectly disrupts the flow of the sentence as you suggested.

The mix of tenses gives the reader a sense of continuity, that events have happened and continue to happen.  It also seems to convey a wider time scale, that these are not new events; whereas "**business ventures are formed, run, and managed by women**" suggests now or in the future.

Answer (score 0):

In a comment Edwin Ashworth wrote:

> The comma 'rules' are not absolute and are 'given' / used to (1) guarantee clarity of meaning, (2) aid reading, (3) show emphasis by signalling say dramatic pauses, (4 ) fit in with a certain style. If too many commas of different types are evident in a sentence, it is best to rephrase. Especially when different rules seem to be in play and it is difficult to work out which should take precedence. // 'Interestingly enough, a large number of the Facebook-based business ventures were formed, and are run and managed, by women. This directly and indirectly contributes to women's empowerment....'

Answer (score -1):

The use of the tense depends upon what event happened first and what followed thereafter. ***Facebook-based business ventures*** were first formed which is a one time event. Then, the ventures ***are run and managed*** by women who were hired after the formation of the venture.

Hence, the tense for formation is in present-perfect form and the other two verbs are in simple past tense.

P.S. "are run and managed" is equivalent to "are run and are managed" where *run* is in past form.